# Create Azure metrics alert for failedLocationCount

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-alerts

I want to create a Azure metrics alert for a Webtest that fires in case a number of locations has failed. I can create this manully than it shows a condition name "Whenever the average failed locations is greater than or equal to 1".

I tried to create this with azure cli command:

```
$aiId = "<Application Insights Azure-Id>"
$actionGroupId = "<Action Group Azure-Id>"
az monitor metrics alert create -n myAlertName -g myRgName --scopes $aiId --condition "avg availabilityResults/failedLocationCount >= 1" --action $actionGroupId --auto-mitigate true --severity 1
```

failing with: `(BadRequest) Couldn't find a metric named availabilityResults/failedLocationCount. Make sure the name is correct.` I also tried --condition "avg failedLocationCount >= 1"`` with same result. Working is `--condition "avg availabilityResults/availabilityPercentage <= 85"` but I don't want it not on percentage.

For the manual deployed alert I can show the settings via `az monitor metrics alert list` saying:

```
"criteria": {
  "additionalProperties": null,
  "componentId": "/subscriptions/xxx",
  "failedLocationCount": 1.0,
  "odataType": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.WebtestLocationAvailabilityCriteria",
  "webTestId": "/subscriptions/xxx"
}
```

My last test was to use the Webtest Azure-Id instead of the Application Insights Azure-Id with no success. (Error message: microsoft.insights/webtests is not a supported platform metric namespace)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue and almost no documentation on the mentioned  requirment